# How to return multiple columns using vlookup in Excel?

Tags: excel, formula, multiple-columns, lookup, vlookup

Let suppose i have 2 tables with below data. I want to return all three columns of a row(each row at a time) of table A, when location of table A found in the locations(look for all locations) of table B using vlookup.
e.g: 
step 1: first location of table A = 1
step 2: look for location 1 in table B.
step 3: If found then return first row of table B.

Please see the below example and expected result.

Table A

```
Location    Quantity    Amount
  1           10         100
  2           20         400
  3           30         500
  4           40         600
  5           50         700
```

Table B

```
Location    Quantity    Amount
1            30          34
3             4          34
4             5          3454
6            65          565
7            66          76
```

Expected result:

```
Location    Quantity    Amount
1            10         100
N/A         N/A         N/A
3           30          500
4           40          600
N/A        N/A          N/A
```

I have been doing this for so long but couldn't find the solution yet.
I have millions of records and cannot do it manually. Your answer would be highly appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You just need an If formula. Assuming Table A is in Columns A, B, C, and Table B is next to it in Columns D, E, F then wherever Table C is you'll want something like: =IF(A2=D2,A2,"") in the first column, =IF(A2=D2,B2,"") in the second, =IF(A2=D2,C2,"") in the third.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Comment: i have made some changes in the question.. please look at it again.. I want the location of table A to be searched inthe location of table B, if found the return the row of table A

Comment: Do you mean return the Row where the Location from A is found in B? For example, in your set above in A there is Location 4 found on Row 5. You need to know that Location 4 is found in B on Row 4. (These rows count the headers of course.)

Comment: If you use the Match formula it returns the (first) row where that searched value is found. '=MATCH(A2,D:D,0)' So that searches Column D for the value listed in A# and if it finds a match gives you the Row on which it was found.